How to Implement Unique PCB Identification for Automatic Configuration Selection on Raspberry Pi?
I'm working on a project where a Raspberry Pi runs a script that controls LEDs on different PCBs. While the script is identical for each PCB, the configuration settings vary between them. I want to automate the process of selecting the correct configuration file by having the Raspberry Pi identify which PCB is connected.
Is there a reliable method to embed a unique identifier into each PCB, such that the Raspberry Pi can read this identifier and automatically load the corresponding configuration? I'm interested in approaches that involve hardware or components that can serve as this identifier.
Any guidance on how to implement such a system would be greatly appreciated.

Can you set a limit on the total number of possible different boards?

We have around 50 different boards, but we add more in the future.

If you are "loading" the configuration onto the boards, that implies some sort of memory already on them, or do I mistake?

How many GPIO's do you have available? Pulling up or down six GPIO's gives you six bits, which allows you to identity PCB 0 to 63.

Do you need to uniquely identify the board, or is it enough that you cannot tell two boards apart if they have same configuration? Do you have an upper limit for board count, how many you add? Up to 256, up to 65536, up to 16 million, 4 billion, more than that - throw a number? Do you plan to use some sort of bus like I2C or SPI? Other bus? How are the boards controlled or LEDs on it?

One inexpensive approach that can work well is to embed a serial EEPROM such as the 24C02. If you already have an I2C bus connection then it may not require any more connections. The RPi has an I2C bus, you only need to enable it.
The downside is that it has to be programmed somehow, but that can be done during testing. This is a Chinese one, but there are many suppliers such as Microchip. Available in SO-8 or SOT-23 so little real estate is consumed as well.
The 24C02 (one of the smaller ones) is organized 256 x 8 so you have plenty of memory to store a board code with redundancy, store a human-readable description, store an individual serial number, date of manufacture, CRC etc.

There are at least two approaches.
Store the configuration itself on the board, no unique ID needed. The unique ID will then be irrelevant. If some boards have identical configuration then they can't be separated which one is which if this is important. Then you need the unique ID.
Another approach is to have unique ID for each board. There exists chips that offer a guaranteed unique ID as a sole function or just additionally to some other primary function. But then your Raspberry Pi must have some kind of database or configuration file or other storage for each unique ID ever seen from which to determine what the configuration should be. If you lose that database then you don't have the configuration any more. But at least you can identify the boards based on unique ID and have no clue what the configuration needs to be.
As a next step, you can assign each board an unique ID yourself by storing it on the board. If it looks like board has never been plugges in, the memory is empty and you can generate an ID and write it to board memory. It's up to you to generate the IDs somehow - maybe an increasing serial number, or generate a practically random ID somehow, like UUID, or just assume that each time you detect an unprogrammed board and need an ID, just use unix timestamp for date and time of board initialization.
